# What would cause nvprof to return no data?

Tags: cuda, fortran, mpi, openacc, nvprof

I have a Fortran MPI code instrumented with OpenACC.  It is a big code.  No way I can provide any meaningful snippets here.  It runs fine under Cray aprun:

```
aprun -n 15 ./mycode
```

I want to profile it with nvprof.  I try:

```
aprun -n 15 -b nvprof ./mycode
```

The code again runs OK, but when all is said and done, I get no profiling data, just a message:

```
======== Warning: No CUDA application was profiled, exiting
```

There is no other error message provided.  Anyone have any idea what would cause this behavior?  I am compiling with the Cray MPI Fortran compiler.  My compile flags are

```
-Mdaz -traceback -Ktrap=inv -acc -ta=tesla,cuda6.5,cc35,nofma -Minfo=accel -Mcuda=cuda6.5,cc35 -I. -module .
```

The `cudatoolkit` module is loaded.

Comment: Likely an issue where the app exits but the profiler buffers aren't flushed. The information in this [NVIDIA tip](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/pro-tip-clean-up-after-yourself-ensure-correct-profiling/) may help.

Comment: @njuffa Do you know if there are Fortran equivalents for those routines?  Thanks.

Comment: You should be able to call C code from Fortran. If your compiler supports Fortran 2003, I would suggest using ISO C bindings, otherwise use the toolchain specific method described in you compiler's documentation.

Comment: @njuffa Tried it.  Now getting "call to cuMemFreeHost returned error 709: Context is destroyed or not yet created"  Any idea what that might be about?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I am not familiar with the Cray environment or `aprun`. The answer by KVM below (which you might want to try) seems to suggest that `aprun` is a program used to spawn other programs as a child process, which may be part of the problem with profiling. It is also possible that there is a bug in your application that causes abnormal program termination of the CUDA program, preventing profiler buffers to be flushed upon proper termination. This is suggested by the error message about the destroyed CUDA context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
aprun -n 15 -b nvprof --profile-child-processes ./mycode
```

For cray systems, you run aprun from a login node. aprun launches processes on compute nodes. By default, nvprof will not profile the child processes, so the `--profile-child-processes` option profiles the spawned processes.

Comment: Perhaps some comment what the line does and why?

Comment: @KVM: Not being familiar with the Cray platform and `aprun`, I assume adding `--profile-child-processes` fixes the asker's problem, because without it `nvprof` will be applied to `aprun` itself, rather than the CUDA application it launches? It would be helpful if you could expand and clarify your answer in that regard.

Comment: Not out of the woods yet, but it looks like this was a step forward.  Thanks.